# There is no ubuntu kernel version i'm looking for

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt

I have two ubuntu server(20.04.5). The one has kernel version 5.4.0-137-generic, and the other has kernel version 5.15.0-66-generic. I want to make them have same kernel version (5.15.0-66-generic). But when i ran `sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.15.0-66-generic` command, following error message occured.

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-5.15.0-66-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-5.15.0-66-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-5.15.0-66-generic'
```

When i checked available kernel version in the list, there is no kernel version i was looking for in the list.

```
sudo apt-cache search linux-image-5. | grep 5.15.0-


linux-image-5.15.0-1003-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1006-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1007-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1007-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1008-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1008-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1010-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1011-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1012-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1013-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1013-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1013-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1014-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1014-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1014-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1015-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1015-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1015-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1016-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1016-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1016-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1016-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1017-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1017-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1017-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1017-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1017-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1018-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1018-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1018-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1019-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1019-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1019-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1019-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1020-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1020-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1020-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1021-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1021-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1021-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1021-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1021-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1022-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1022-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1022-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1022-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1023-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1023-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1023-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1023-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1025-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1025-intel-iotg - Signed kernel image intel-iotg
linux-image-5.15.0-1025-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1026-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1026-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1027-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1027-gcp - Signed kernel image GCP
linux-image-5.15.0-1027-gke - Signed kernel image gke
linux-image-5.15.0-1027-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1028-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1029-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1029-gcp - Signed kernel image gcp
linux-image-5.15.0-1029-oracle - Signed kernel image oracle
linux-image-5.15.0-1030-aws - Signed kernel image aws
linux-image-5.15.0-1030-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1031-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1033-azure - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-33-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-33-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-42-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-43-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-46-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-48-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-50-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-52-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-53-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-56-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-57-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-58-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-58-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-60-generic - Signed kernel image generic
linux-image-5.15.0-60-lowlatency - Signed kernel image lowlatency
linux-image-5.15.0-1003-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1005-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1007-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1008-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1011-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1012-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1013-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1015-gkeop - Signed kernel image gkeop
linux-image-5.15.0-1019-azure-fde - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1020-azure-fde - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1021-azure-fde - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1029-azure-fde - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1030-azure-fde - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1031-azure-fde - Signed kernel image azure
linux-image-5.15.0-1033-azure-fde - Signed kernel image azure
```

I would like to know why this happened and the way to address this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linux-image-5.15.0-66-generic` was a proposed update for Jammy (22.04, not 20.04), but it didn’t graduate to the updates repository; it’s been replaced by [`linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/5.15.0-67.74).

If both servers are running 20.04, you should stick to the 5.4 kernels which are [supported on 20.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/linux). The latest released 5.4 kernel package is 5.4.0-139, with 5.4.0-144 in proposed updates.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now i can understand what kernel version should i use and get to know there is a repository called proposed update. I realize that i registered the proposed repo using `add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/proposed` command about two weeks ago. Now i would like to know how can i remove the reference to proposed repo and add update repository. When i look through  `/etc/apt/sources.list`, i think proposed repo isn’t there.

Comment: To remove a repository, add the `-r` flag: `add-apt-repository -r ppa:canonical-kernel-team/proposed`.